# ZipArchive downloading selected images is failing with large download

Tags: php, html, php-ziparchive

I've created a web page that displays a list of thumbnail images. The user can select the images by using a check box next to the thumbnail and then download the selected images.

The form actions a download php file which creates the zipped file with the ZipArchive function and then removes the file once downloaded.

Here's the HTML form with one the markup for one of the images:

```
<form name="download" method="post" action="includes/download.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="zipname" value="images.zip">
  <input class="button" type="submit" value="Download Selected">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <img src="images/image_01_thumb.jpg"/>
      <input type="checkbox" name="files[]" value="images/image_01.jpg">
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

and the php download file contains:

```
$files = $_POST['files'];
$zipname = $_POST['zipname'];
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
foreach ($files as $file) {
  $zip->addFile($file);
}
$zip->close();

header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$zipname);
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));
readfile($zipname);
unlink ($zipname);

?>
```

So far this is working great until the file exceeds 150MB and then fails. When it tries to download the large file it times out and I get a 'File not found error", after the error I can see that the zip file was created and contains all the selected files (so I know it's partly working) but as it timed out it also failed to remove the zipped file.

I've checked the maximum file size for the ZipArchive function and unless I'm mistaken it should be able to handle files up to 4gb. Does any know why this may be happening?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: This script is vulnerable, e.g. when I request `index.php` it's getting put into ZIP file, too.

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for commenting. Would this cause the issue I'm experiencing? Also, to help me understand, how would you also request the index.php in the described scenario?

Comment: POST and GET values can be easily manipulated. I just put `index.php` in `$_POST['files'][] = 'index.php';` I could also try to download your whole sourcecode then.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I'll look into it further. If anyones curious, the issue I described was being caused due a PHP data limit which was a server default.